# scala - implementing trait method with parameter that is child of expected type

Tags: scala, methods, parameters, match, extends

I'm very new to Scala so forgive me if this is a real easy question but I could not find anything to help me or I could not figure out the right search terms. How can I make this work?

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> class FooImpl extends Foo
defined class FooImpl

scala> trait Bar { def someMethod(foo: Foo) }
defined trait Bar

scala> class BarImpl extends Bar { def someMethod(foo: FooImpl) {} }
<console>:10: error: class BarImpl needs to be abstract, since method someMethod in trait Bar of type (foo: Foo)Unit is not defined
(Note that Foo does not match FooImpl)
       class BarImpl extends Bar { def someMethod(foo: FooImpl) {} }
```

Why doesn't FooImpl match Foo since Foo is a trait? I'm guessing I need to alter the signature of someMethod in Bar to say that I'm expecting something that extends Foo or "with Foo" but I can't seem to find documentation for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dhg explained why this doesn't work and why you probably don't really want it.

But if you still want it, you can do it like this:

```
trait Foo

class FooImpl extends Foo

trait Bar[F <: Foo] { def someMethod(foo: F) }

class BarImpl extends Bar[FooImpl] {
    def someMethod(foo: FooImpl) {}
}
```

Comment: Accepted this because it solved my issue. Is "F <: Foo" basically "something that extends Foo"?

Comment: Yes F <: Foo means Foo or something extending Foo.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `Bar` trait's `someMethod` declaration specifies that any kind of `Foo` can be passed as an argument.  You can think of this as its "contract".  The contract says that any implementation of `Bar` will have a method `someMethod` that will accept any kind of `Foo`.

Your `BarImpl` class is an implementation of `Bar` and has a `someMethod` implementation.  Unfortunately, its implementation of `someMethod` **only** accepts `FooImpl` kinds of `Foo` objects: not **any** kind of `Foo`.  Since it doesn't allow you to pass in `Foo` objects that aren't `FooImpl` objects, it violates the contract specified by the trait definition.  Implementations can't be more restrictive than the contract specifies.

As an example:

```
class FooImplB extends Foo
val bar: Bar = new BarImpl
val foo: Foo = new FooImplB
bar.someMethod(foo)
```

Here we declare a `Bar` called `bar` and a `Foo` called `foo`.  According to the definition of `Foo` I should be able to pass `foo` into `bar.someMethod`.  Except that `BarImpl.someMethod` only accepts `FooImpl` kinds of `Foo`s and not `FooImplB`s!  So we have a problem.

Comment: I guess I got so used to doing this in Groovy I forgot you can't do this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Jens Schauder's answer works but forces you to define the type in the trait signature. Instead, you can  do the same on the method level:

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> class FooImple extends Foo
defined class FooImple

scala> trait Bar { def methodA[T <: Foo](foo: T) }
defined trait Bar

scala> class BarImpl extends Bar { def methodA[FooImpl](foo: FooImpl){} }
defined class BarImpl
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better answer IMO.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Even after you fix the typo (`FooImple` / `FooImpl`), the `FooImpl` in the last line is a new type parameter that shadows the `FooImpl` class, so you could call it with a string or integer as an argument, for example, which is very much not what you want. Jens's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @TravisBrown you're right. I hadn't noticed the typo which really points out the problem. The compiler isn't complaining even though FooImpl has not been defined. I verified Jens' answer to work in Eclipse for my project. I'll switch answers back.